# how is the salt for user password hash created when creating a new user, for use with crypt() after?

Tags: linux, authentication, salt, crypt

currently making a little analysis on the authentication based on password on linux, i understood the following :

users passwords hashes are stored in /etc/shadow, with the salt used to generate them. The id also provide the algorithm used to get the hash. To verify if a password is correct, we pass the id and the salt to the crypt function, generate a temporary hash and compare it to the hash registered.

However, when you create a new user for example, you need to populate that shadow file with hash and salt. Hash is of course obtained by calling crypt function, but i can't figure out how is the salt generated when invoking that crypt function.

Indeed, from what i have read and understoof of the libc code relative to crypt function, there is nothing relative to generate a random salt. We can provide crypt with a random salt we have created by hand when creating a new user, but we almost always create users without providing salts for their password hashing.

So, how is that salt generated the first time when creating a user? Is /dev/random used?

I would appreciate some code or commands in the answer.

thanks!

Comment: The `DEV/URANDOM` is the right source to read from, but different algorithms may have different requirements for the salt (BCrypt for example accepts only characters of a given alphabet).

Comment: @martinstoeckli What makes you think that the` bcrypt` salt "accepts only characters of a given alphabet"? That is incorrect.

Comment: @zaph - The algorithm BCrypt does accept any salt, but not the implementation of the [crypt()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) utility, which is what the php function used to call. It requires an encoded salt of the following alphabet `./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`. The newer `password_hash()` function accepts any salt, but transforms it to this alphabet (if necessary) before calling the crypt function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard function to generate the salt but every good library should generate a random one for you. As written in another comment some salts have to be of a specific alphabet like "A-Za-z0-9./" for crypt() while others accept random data.

For Java, look at the Apache Commons Codec project which implements a Unix crypt() compatible function. It's a simple for loop that choses random characters from a given alphabet:

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/B64.java#B64.getRandomSalt%28int%29

Comment: Quoting from crypt(3): "salt is a two-character string chosen from the set [a-zA-Z0-9./]" (for traditional DES based crypt) and later down: "The characters in "salt" and "encrypted" are drawn from the set [a-zA-Z0-9./]."

Maybe there are algorithms that accept arbitrary 8-bit random data but some don't and the original question was specifically about crypt().
(

Comment: I changed "most" to "some" and you change that -1 back, ok? :-)

Comment: bcrypt() and pbkdf2() should be used over crypt in new work.

Comment: indeed, it seems there is no standard function to do so. @zaph, most distrib use SHA-256 right now in that crypt function